# Google Analytics events are not working even following Google's developer tutorial

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, dom-events

I'm trying to get an event when I'm pressing a button but I can't see any clue of my activity on my Google Analytics page.
I followed the Google Analytics tutorial in this page https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Following that instructions I've created a button with the id "button":

```
<a id="button"><btn class="btn btn-default">Button</btn></a></p>
```

then I have included in the head of the document the main Google Analytics call to connect my page to the right database (I've changed UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'myname.com with my current settings)

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'myname.com');  //create a tracker
      ga('send', 'pageview');                               //send a pageview
</script>
```

and lastly I paste that code on the bottom of the page that should track the event:

```
<script>
    var downloadLink = document.getElementById('button');
    addListener(downloadLink, 'click', function() {
        ga('send', 'test', 'button', 'click', 'nav-buttons');
        console.log("clicked and sent (hopefully)");
    });


    /**
     * Utility to wrap the different behaviors between W3C-compliant browsers
     * and IE when adding event handlers.
     *
     * @param {Object} element Object on which to attach the event listener.
     * @param {string} type A string representing the event type to listen for
     *     (e.g. load, click, etc.).
     * @param {function()} callback The function that receives the notification.
     */
    function addListener(element, type, callback) {
     if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, callback);
     else if (element.attachEvent) element.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
    }
</script>
```

It looks right to me: the id is "button" and it should trigger the call to the event. But it's not working! I don't receive anything from Google's dashboard so I can't understand what's wrong with my jJavascript.

Comment: Is `"clicked and sent (hopefully)"` showing up in your console?

Comment: Yes it is, that's why I don't understand what's happening...

Comment: I have linked it in the first lines. You linked to me the "ga" one but I'm using "analytics.js" that is the latest version. Can you see the link?

Comment: Change `ga('send', 'test', 'button', 'click', 'nav-buttons');` to `ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav-buttons');`

Comment: It worked! It was an easy one! Write it down, I'll check your answer as the right one (: Thank you!

Comment: Cool, there you go! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
ga('send', 'test', 'button', 'click', 'nav-buttons');
```

to

```
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav-buttons');
```